# C typedef function prototype with struct attempting to reference before defined.

Tags: c, struct

I need to reference a struct that's not yet defined because the struct actually conatins the typedef'd function prototype.

For example,

```c
typedef int (MyCallbackFunction)(X * x, void * ctx);

typedef struct CallbackData {
  MyCallbackFunction * callback;
  void * ctx;
} CallbackData;

typedef struct X {
  char a;
  int b;
  int c;
  double d;

  CallbackData e;
} X;
```

What's the valid way to actually write this code/header ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just forward declare the relevant types - and you can make the function pointer part of the typedef:

```
struct X_;

typedef int (*MyCallbackFunction)(struct X_ * x, void * ctx);

typedef struct CallbackData_ {
  MyCallbackFunction callback;
  void * ctx;
} CallbackData;

typedef struct X_ {
  char a;
  int b;
  int c;
  double d;

  CallbackData e;
} X;
```

Comment: Will this work if I pass in a callback function that uses for example: `int callback(X * x, void * ctx)`, or will the compiler complain that `X` is different from `struct X`?

Comment: Sorry, I fixed it -- I generally prefer to give the `struct` and its typedef different names so you can unambiguously refer to both as needed. See the edit.

Answer (score 5):

Just forward declare your `typedef`s

```
typedef struct X X;
typedef struct CallbackData CallbackData;
```

and then declare the `struct`s later.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can forward declare the struct and use it in the declaration of `MyCallbackFunction` where you don't need it to be a complete type.

```
struct X;
typedef int (MyCallbackFunction)(struct X * x, void * ctx);
```